# Streaming audio over a bluetooth socket

Tags: windows, sockets, audio, stream, bluetooth

I need to stream audio over Windows sockets to a bluetooth headset.
I am able to make socket connection to the Bluetooth headset using RFCOMM and A2DP / Headset profile / Hands-free profile.
My requirement is to stream audio (`WAV` or `MP3`) over the socket.
Is it possible by simply writing audio data to the socket (using send())?
OR any other ways to do it?

I am required to use the same socket connection to stream. If I use Media Control Interface APIs, they will make a separate connection and then stream.

Answer (score 0):

The A2DP profile is layered on top of L2CAP and SDP; moreover SDP shall function 
while using L2CAP as its transport protocol.

So if you want to implement the communication with send(s) through a socket, you need to implement SPD also, and you should realize the communication as specified in

https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=8236

after you have connected serially to your A2DP capable device, like i. e. using:

http://SimpleBluetooth4Win.Sourceforge.net

(small library that uses the windows bluetooth networking API)